# Angular2 : importing lodash.clone only (cherry-pick)

Tags: angular, lodash

I read [this article](https://medium.com/@armno/til-importing-lodash-into-angular-the-better-way-aacbeaa40473) and decided to optimize the lodash import in my app but it does not seem to work as explained.

The existing code was :

```
import * as _ from "lodash";
[...]
let clonedObject = _.clone(myObject);
```

Then I tried :

```
import clone from "lodash/clone";
[...]
let clonedObject = clone(myObject);
```

But I got this error at runtime :

```
ERROR TypeError: clone_1.default is not a function
```

So I tried with the curly brace :

```
import {clone} from "lodash/clone";
[...]
let clonedObject = clone(myObject);
```

And this time I got :

```
ERROR TypeError: clone_1.clone is not a function
```

Finally it worked with :

```
import *  as clone from "lodash/clone";
[...]
let clonedObject = clone(myObject);
```

And the lodash website is talking about something like :

```
var clone = require('lodash/clone');
```

Finally, what is the correct and most efficient way to import a lodash function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Angular 2+ I use this syntax `import *  as clone from "lodash/clone";`. 
You can `console.log(clone)` to see that it prints only the function `clone` you need.

I guess `var clone = require('lodash/clone');` is for nodejs.

Comment: Any idea why `import clone from "lodash/clone";` does not work ?

Comment: i am not totally sure maybe they need to `export default`, or maybe the problem is when you export from .js file and try to import it in .ts file. If you find the answer let us know also :)